# Как реализовать такой эффект?

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, html, css

Столкнулся с проблемой, использование PHP в JQuery. Нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на ссылку остальные предметы пропадали и появлялись новые заместо них. Проблема вот в чем: предметы (т.е. картинки), которые должны появиться, должны быть вытащенными из БД (Базы Данных).

Помогите, пожалуйста, реализовать это. И скажите, пожалуйста, как сделать запрос в базу данных и вытащить из них картинки. Заранее сердечно благодарен!

Comment: При чем тут jQuery? Ты не умеешь с PHP работать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно организовать запрос в БД силами, со стороны клиента, jQuery и PHP - на сервере. Для этого нужно воспользоваться $.ajax() или $.post().
Как это сделать:

```
function ajax_query() {
    $("action_element").click(function () {
        var options = {
            url: 'path_to/file.php',
            data: 'param1=' + value1,
            type: 'POST',
            // 'json', 'get' etc  
            cache: false,
            success: function (text) {
                $("#result_element").html(text);
            }
        };
        $.ajax(options);
    });
}
```

Ну, и дописывайте в функции при выполнении скрипта нужные действия с добавлением элементов DOM, тут уже на сколько фантазии хватит!

Comment: `path_to/file.php` - а сюда что нужно вписывать? если картинки находятся в БД, а не в файле PHP??

Comment: Адрес скрипта. Картинка у вас в виде ссылки?!

Comment: dataType не мешало бы указать в аякс-запросе. Ведь данные скорее всего будут отдаваться в виде json(так логичнее и удобнее, имхо), а если не указать тип данных - будет фэйл =\
Лично от себя добавлю, что было бы неплохо передавать доп. переменную в ответе, например {'success' : true}, и потом по ней в ветке success: function(data) проверять, удачный был запрос или нет. Фишка-то в том, что ветка 'success' выполнится всегда, когда запрос не закрАшился в обработчике. А ситуации разные бывают...

Comment: да картинка в БД находиться в виде ссылки.

Comment: path_to/file.php - это скрипт-обработчик, возвращающий массив ссылок, которые он должен выдрать из базы.

Comment: @metazet Можно на сервере посылать не 2xx код в случае ошибки.